# Should I upgrade to ubuntu 14.10 Utopic Unicorn?

Tags: upgrade, 14.10

Ubuntu 14.10 Utopic Unicorn released yesterday. I'm  using Ubuntu 14.04 since it released.
I want to know what are the new features in 14.10 . Is it really effective to upgrade to 14.10 or 14.04 is best because it is LTS ?

Through searches I came to know few features like :

1.Ubuntu 14.10 uses version 3.16 of the Linux kernel.

2.There are also new versions of LibreOffice, the GNOME components.

So what an average user will get by upgrading to 14.10.

Comment: 14.04 will also receive 3.16 in due time.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.10 still has some bugs. Visit the [Ubuntu 14.10 Release Notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UtopicUnicorn/ReleaseNotes) and scroll down to the **Known issues** heading. Ubuntu 14.04 is more stable right now.

Comment: I suppose you meant "I am using Ubuntu 14.**04** since it released"...

Comment: I recently upgraded to 14.10 from 14.04 . After certain installation issues I am quite  pleased with the update .
Out of the box the following things are fixed 1)  Better smoother working Nouveau display driver for Nvidia cards.  I can now hibernate without crashing .2) Better working Synaptics touchpad on Unity .

Answer (score 4):

Don't upgrade to 14.10 unless you are prepared to upgrade every six months. 14.10 and future releases until the next LTS only have security support for nine months. If you do not upgrade to each successive release on the 6-monthly schedule, you will end up without support.

Another good way of thinking about this is backwards. When was the last time you upgraded before 14.04? Was it more than six months ago? In that case, 14.10 is probably not for you.

I say this because I see questions from users on older interim releases that are no longer supported. Since they did not upgrade on the six-monthly cadence, with hindsight they would clearly have been better off sticking to an LTS release.

Answer (score 3):

14.04 is an LTS, meaning it [will be supported for 5 years (until April 2019)](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases). This should cover security and critical fixes.

So, if this is a production machine in which you need stability over everything, or you are just not willing to upgrade every 6 months, just stick with the LTS.

Otherwise, if you want the latest and greatest, and are willing to upgrade every 6 months, go for 14.10. It's working great in my machines.

On the question: "what an average user will get by upgrading to 14.10". Well, at a quick glance, not much. Mostly, more up to date versions of applications.