# Ubuntu Latest Stable Version

Tags: 12.04

I want to use Ubuntu as a Desktop.Currently i am using 14.04 as a desktop.
What is the latest stable version which should i use that is free from Vulnerability so that we can move forward.

Comment: The latest stable release that is LTS 14.04.2 http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Answer (score 0):

[Ubuntu 14.10](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) is the latest stable Ubuntu version you can use . **Scroll down** to the page for download link

Comment: Ubuntu 14.10 is devel release (*development) it's not the latest stable and its support will be ended in July, 2015.

Answer (score -1):

14.10 is the latest. http://www.ubuntu.com/download is the download page. 
Though, I would recommend update-manager to upgrade to the next version keeping the current in the same place. 
more instructions here.

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/upgrade

Today is the release date for the latest and the greatest release is later tonight according to the release schedule given below.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/VividVervet/ReleaseSchedule

Comment: Ubuntu 14.10 is devel release (*development) it's not the latest stable and its support will be ended in July, 2015. And so is 15.04  Vivid Vervet is the devel release and will be supported only till 2016.

Comment: @joker I disagree, all ubuntu releases are stable releases. There are different support cycles.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Version_timeline

Ubuntu does not have unstable/testing releases.

Comment: development release cannot be that stable as it's being tested and run with new features and environments to make the future LTS release the best and that's a cycles of development not just support but to succeed from one release to another (alfa-beta) and to LTS release. Read more on [development](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDevelopment/ReleaseProcess)

Comment: @JoKeR where does it mention as development release? It is a full release with short term support. As a desktop OS, such short product life cycles are acceptable.

Comment: run in terminal `man do-release-upgrade` then you'll understand.

Comment: @JoKeR doesn't say anything about stable or otherwise on the command you mentioned.

Comment: read closer `-d, --devel-release Check if upgrading to the latest devel release is possible`

Comment: You are right about development release. Ubuntu does not consider it unstable though. The standards are the same for both release cycles, except one has longer support cycle.

Comment: @JoKeR did you read the [Development](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDevelopment/ReleaseProcess) link you just mentioned. It mentions the alpha and beta are considered as the development releases. Then it is finalized for release. After that all bugs are fixed in Stable Release Updates. which is there in both april and october releases. Hope, it clarifies things :-)

edit. : fixed the link

Comment: @JoKeR so I am validated in saying that 14.10 is a stable release. it is not a LTS release, but still a stable release

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23102/discussion-between-viyyer-and-joker).

Comment: my opinion like this and always been http://askubuntu.com/questions/540866/should-i-upgrade-to-ubuntu-14-10-utopic-unicorn

Comment: You are totally entitled to your opinion. I would often recommend LTS release for critical projects. But as a new user, any ubuntu release is just as good. why not go for the latest and the greatest. :-)

Comment: :-) it is clearly explained in a link I've just posted.